# Implementing a Distributed Queue

Tags: c#, algorithm, message-queue, distributed-computing

I would like to implement (in c#) a **distributed** and **concurrent** message queue. I am well aware that there are implementations and some source code available (such as RhinoQueue, RabbitMQ, ...).

What I am interested in, is some **papers or other literature** that describe various **algorithms** behind a reliable and durable message queue (how the data should be partitioned, propagated,  eventual consistency is ensured...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [ActiveMQ by Apache](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-distributed-queues-work.html). It May help. In addition, take a look at [this question at stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16638/what-are-the-solutions-to-the-distributed-queue-problem).

Comment: Thanks, Apache website is helpful indeed